# Rails avoiding N+1 has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have the following imaginary class

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :objects, -> { order(:created_at) }, class_name: 'B'
  has_one :last_object, -> { order(created_at: :desc).limit(1) }, class_name: 'B'

  scope :with_last_object, -> { includes(:last_object) }
end
```

I added a second association to model A and the scope to avoid N+1 request in the next case:`A.all.map(&:last_object)`. So I write `A.all.with_last_object.map(&:last_object)`.
But it fails: it retrieve only 1 `last_object` for all instances of A. From Postgres Logs

```
 SELECT  "b".* FROM "b" WHERE "b"."a_id" IN (1, 2, 3, ...) ORDER BY "b"."created_at" DESC LIMIT $1
```

Is there a way to avoid N+1 issue in this situation?

Comment: you shouldn't have a `limit(1)` on a `has_one`, `has_one` already limits for you.

Comment: yes, but in that case, it makes a request on all `b` relation which might take much time

Comment: No, `limit(1)` does nothing here, from a performance standpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with this (thanks to my colleague)

```
has_one :last_object, -> {
    from(
      <<~SQL
        (select * from
          (select
              *,
              row_number() over(partition by b.a_id order by b.created_at desc) as rn
          from
              b) as inner_b
        where rn = 1) as b
      SQL
    )
  }, class_name: 'B', dependent: :delete
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your definition of the `last_object`, which active record is not able to convert into an eager load.

Either you play hard with self-joins, so you can have some tricky (and possibly underperforming) SQL like

```
SELECT  "b".* FROM "b"
JOIN "b" AS "b_from_same_a"
  ON "b"."a_id" = "b_from_same_a"."id"
WHERE "b"."created_at" = MAX("b_from_same_a"."created_at")
GROUP BY "b".*
```

or you can explicitly track the last one:

```
class B < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :set_last, on: :create

  def set_last
    self.class.where(a_id: a_id).update_all(last: false)
    self.update_column(last: true)
  end
end
```

and modify your association scopes accordingly.

Comment: Only concern with option 2 is deletion of the "last" record. Would certainly need a destruction hook as well